# Stack overflow content appearing in somebody else' blog

Tags: discussion

I was just checking to see what is being posted about myself on the net by Googling 'Weedy101' and found to my surprise that a website called Blogosfera.co.uk is quoting one of my questions I posted here on stack overflow without any accreditation for where it came from or who asked the question.

Here is the blog post http://www.blogosfera.co.uk/2013/10/php-get_magic_quotes_gpc-how-can-i-strip-the-inserted-escape-characters/

Is this a case of stack overflow content being 'pirated', or is there some other reason for it?